# If $f$ is injective (resp. surjective), is $af$ injective (resp. surjective)?

Tags: functions

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and $af:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, with $a\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, be the scalar multiple of $f$.
I was wondering if $f$ is injective (respectively surjective), is $af$ also injective (respectively surjective)?

Comment: Does $af$ mean a scalar multiple of $f$? If so, take $a = 0$.

Comment: Yeah but $a$ can't be 0

Comment: For nonzero $a$, $af$ is injective (or surjective) if $f$ is injective (or surjective, respectively). This is an immediate result by the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is an injective function. Then $f(x) = f(y) \iff x = y$. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. Let's see that $af$ is also injective. If $af(x) = af(y)$, then $\frac{1}{a}af(x) = \frac{1}{a}af(y)$. Thus, $f(x) = f(y)$. Since $f$ is an injective function, it follows that $x = y$. Therefore, $af$ is an injective function.

Now, assume that $f$ is a surjective function. Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $f$ is a surjective function it follows that there exists $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = \frac{y}{a}$. Then, we have that $af(x) = y$. Thus, $af$ is a surjective function.